# merging the results of a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

i am trying to merge the results of this query all data in one list. 'Union' didnt help...

any ideas ?

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @items AS VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @stline AS VARCHAR(500)



while @cnt < 101

begin 

set @items = 'LG_0' + convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + '_ITEMS'
set @stline = 'LG_0' + convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + '_01_STLINE'

if (OBJECT_ID (@items) is not null and OBJECT_ID(@stline) is not null ) 

set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT
    ITM1.CODE, itm1.NAME, max (stl.date_) [latest date] , price as [latest price], '+ convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + ' as [proje kodu]

FROM ' + @items + ' ITM1 INNER JOIN ' + @stline +  ' STL 
    ON ITM1.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE PRICE > 0 
    AND TRCODE = 1 
    AND CANCELLED = 0 
    AND INVOICEREF > 0 


    group by code, name, stl.DATE_ , price

    '

    exec (@SQLQuery)



    set @cnt = @cnt +1 


end
```

the result is this :

[image: Result]

but i want them all union-ed... (sorry for the mostly code issue, i have to add here more typing)

Comment: Honey Badger answered your question below. Another way that I would suggest is using a temp table and keep inserting result into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @items AS VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @stline AS VARCHAR(500)

set @SQLQuery =''

while @cnt < 101

begin 

set @items = 'LG_0' + convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + '_ITEMS'
set @stline = 'LG_0' + convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + '_01_STLINE'

if (OBJECT_ID (@items) is not null and OBJECT_ID(@stline) is not null ) 

set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'SELECT
    ITM1.CODE, itm1.NAME, max (stl.date_) [latest date] , price as [latest price], '+ convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + ' as [proje kodu]

    FROM ' + @items + ' ITM1 INNER JOIN ' + @stline +  ' STL 
        ON ITM1.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
    WHERE PRICE > 0 
        AND TRCODE = 1 
        AND CANCELLED = 0 
        AND INVOICEREF > 0 
    GROUP BY code, name, stl.DATE_ , price

    UNION ALL

    '    
    set @cnt = @cnt +1 
end 

-- SUBSTRING to remove last UNION ALL
--PRINT len(@SQLQuery)

set @SQLQuery = left ( @SQLQuery , len(@SQLQuery)-18)


--PRINT len(@SQLQuery)

-- print @SQLQuery

-- For debugging purposes
-- PRINT @SQLQuery
exec (@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: @honeybadger thanks a lot ! i realized that the last part shall be cut 18 characters , not 10 somehow...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `UNION` didn't work for you, but the following should work:

```
 DECLARE @cnt INT = 0
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''
    DECLARE @items AS VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @stline AS VARCHAR(500)

    while @cnt < 101

    begin 

    set @items = 'LG_0' + convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + '_ITEMS'
    set @stline = 'LG_0' + convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + '_01_STLINE'

    if (OBJECT_ID (@items) is not null and OBJECT_ID(@stline) is not null ) 

    set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'SELECT
        ITM1.CODE, itm1.NAME, max (stl.date_) [latest date] , price as [latest price], '+ convert(nvarchar(3),@cnt) + ' as [proje kodu]

        FROM ' + @items + ' ITM1 INNER JOIN ' + @stline +  ' STL 
            ON ITM1.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
        WHERE PRICE > 0 
            AND TRCODE = 1 
            AND CANCELLED = 0 
            AND INVOICEREF > 0 
        GROUP BY code, name, stl.DATE_ , price

        UNION ALL
        '    
        set @cnt = @cnt +1 

    end 

    -- SUBSTRING to remove last UNION ALL
    SELECT @SQLQuery = SUBSTRING(@SQLQuery, 1, LEN(@SQLQuery) - 18) 

    -- For debugging purposes
    -- PRINT @SQLQuery
    exec (@SQLQuery)
```

I couldn't test it, but you can comment the `exec`, and uncomment the `PRINT` to see what query is being generated. It makes debugging dynamic SQL a whole lot easier.

The idea behind this code: first the `UNION ALL` query is being build, based on your conditions. Finally the last `UNION ALL` is removed, then the code can be executed.

Comment: thanks for your time ...


Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

Comment: Sounds like the SQL is getting executed within the loop, did you place the `exec` outside the loop?

Comment: and when i remove "ALL" 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'Union'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'Union'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'Union'.

Comment: That would make sense if the `exec` is still within the loop: until the loop is exited, the SQL ends in `... UNION ALL`, which is incorrect. That's why you have to `substring` the SQL variable before executing it (outside the loop). Remember to use the `PRINT` function to debug...

Comment: first of all i had to use " set @SQLQuery =''" at the beginning cause sqlquery were coming empty...

<br/>

i think the point is length of the query now. i even used NVARCHAR(max) but the query cuts somewhere in the middle so it gives error...

Comment: After how many characters does the query get 'cut', is the substring working as expected? (Edited answer slightly, initialization of variable was a good catch)

Comment: PRINT len(@SQLQuery) = 9012 (word counted as 3728 as i mentioned) and still i have an error...

Comment: and if you dont add " set @SQLQuery ='' " at the beginning , the length is zero ...